# How to check multiple aspects of a given input

Tags: python

In the program that I am currently creating I need to test if the number is larger than 9 and its last digit is 1, 2, or 3. The code below is not working. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
num = raw_input("Enter a number\n")
lastdigit = int(repr(num)[-1])
if n > 9 and lastdigit == 1 or lastdigit == 2 or lastdigit == 3:
    print "OK"
else:
    print "Not OK"
```

Comment: You set `num` and then check `n`, which is not defined. Besides, `or` has lower priority than `and`, so you should use parentheses.

Comment: You could use `lastdigit in (1,2,3)` also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, a more elegant solution would be:

```
num = int(raw_input("Enter a number\n"))
if num > 9 and (num % 10) in {1, 2, 3}:
    print "OK"
else:
    print "Not OK"
```

Answer (score 1):

You use n variable which is undefined,  you should define n and use ()  for each if condition, or you should convert num to int and change your if statement  :

```
if (num > 9) and ( last_digit in (1,2,3)) :
    print 'Success'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the num to string for checking the last digit. Also use parenthesis when checking for multiple conditions.

```
num = int(raw_input("Enter a number\n"))
lastdigit = str(num)[-1]
if (num > 9) and (lastdigit == '1' or lastdigit == '2' or lastdigit == '3'):
    print "OK"
else:
    print "Not OK"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take mode/modulus of `num` by 10 and you will get the last digit and you can easily compare two numbers.

```
num = raw_input("Enter a number\n")
lastdigit = num%10

if num > 9 and (lastdigit == 1 or lastdigit == 2 or lastdigit == 3):
    print "OK"

else:
    print "Not OK"
```

Comment: In your code `num` is string and yet you are doing modulus operation on it